# ERROR invalid ID 0x0000I304d. ANDROID

Tags: android-sqlite, edittext

Hola a todos necesito ayuda con este problema por favor
Cada vez que intento traer unos datos desde la base de datos mysqlite y pasarlos a unos edittext. me salta  "invalid ID 0x0000I304d" (No sé qué significa ese error)

La base de dato aparentemente está bien y en el listview me muestra toda la información al buscar por ID, pero al querer setear los editext solamente me trae los 2 primeros campos y despues me da ese error,lo unico que se modifica en las reiteradas veces que corrie el programa es  “0x0000I304d.” que supongo es un espacio de memoria.

Este es el codigo del metodo que me da problemas:

```
private void consultar() {
                         SQLiteDatabase db=conn.getReadableDatabase();
                         String[] parametros ={campoid.getText().toString()};

    String[] campos={Utilidades.CAMPO_NOMBRE,
             Utilidades.CAMPO_APELLIDO,
             Utilidades.CAMPO_DNI,
             Utilidades.CAMPO_MATRICULA,
             Utilidades.CAMPO_EMAIL,
             Utilidades.CAMPO_DIRECCION,
             Utilidades.CAMPO_TELEFONO};
    try {
        Cursor cursor=db.query(Utilidades.TABLA_CLIENTES,campos,Utilidades.CAMPO_ID+"=?",parametros,null,null,null );
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        camponombre.setText(cursor.getString(0));
        campoApellido.setText(cursor.getString(1));
        campoDni.setText(cursor.getInt(2));
        campoMatricula.setText(cursor.getInt(3));
        campoEmail.setText(cursor.getString(4));
        campoDireccion.setText(cursor.getString(5));
        campoTelefono.setText(cursor.getInt(6));
        cursor.close();

    }catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"El documento no existe",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}


Lo que indica el LogCat es:

> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) Caused by:
> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID
> #0x4d4 at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:444) at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6412)
```

Comment: Busca en el LogCat donde diga "Caused by" y comenta que dice  esa sección del logCat por favor

Comment: Hola Jorgesys gracias por responder,te paso lo que dice el logCat Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x4d4
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:444)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6412)

Comment: Gracias @Ixam recuerda que el LogCat es indispensable para un desarrollador android. Agrego respuesta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acuerdo a el error mostrado en el `LogCat`,

> Java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) Caused by:
> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID
> #0x4d4 at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:444)

El problema se debe a que usas un valor de tipo entero directamente en tu `TextView` usando `setText()`, lo que cree tu aplicación es que tratas de cargar un recurso que se encuentra en la app pero este no existe,  **para resolver este problema en el caso de los valores enteros usa `String.valueOf(...)` para convertir el valor Int a String**:

```
   try {
            Cursor cursor=db.query(Utilidades.TABLA_CLIENTES,campos,Utilidades.CAMPO_ID+"=?",parametros,null,null,null );
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            camponombre.setText(cursor.getString(0));
            campoApellido.setText(cursor.getString(1));
            campoDni.setText(String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(2)));
            campoMatricula.setText(String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(3)));
            campoEmail.setText(cursor.getString(4));
            campoDireccion.setText(cursor.getString(5));
            campoTelefono.setText(String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(6)));
            cursor.close();

        }catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"El documento no existe",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
```

Comment: ¡¡¡Mil gracias funciono de maravilla!!! :)

Comment: Excelente @Ixam , saludos.